# How to find folder App and MVC on CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

With CakePHP 3, I can't find the folder `App` and folders `Model`, `View`, `Controller`. Is there any difference from CakePHP 2? This is Cakephp3

[image: CakePHP Folder Structure]

Comment: `on Cakephp 3`, `With Cakephp 3`, `this is Cakephp3`, `cakephp-3.0` - are you padding your question with "CakePHP 3.0" to make it long enough to ask? It doesn't sound like you spent much time looking for the mvc folders.

Comment: Thanks your comment I am new in Cakephp version 3 I could not find MVC folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP 3.x now uses the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#application-directory-layout

You should read the migration guide
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html

This can be usefull too
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Answer (score 2):

check your src folder. CakePHP’s src folder is where you will do most of your application development. 
 [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html#the-src-folder)

Comment: In folder "src"  i could see View, Controller but could not find "models"

Answer (score 0):

Optimal way to install cakephp now is composer:

*composer create-project --no-dev cakephp/app .*

CakePhp folder structure

```
config
logs
plugins
src - this is app folder, contains Controller, Model, View
tmp
vendor
    aura - cake core dependency    
    cakephp
        cakephp - cakephp core  
        chronos - cake core dependency (used for datetime functions)
    composer  
    mobiledetect - cake core dependency  
    psr    
    zendframework - cake core dependency
webroot
    css  
    favicon.ico  
    font  
    img  
    js
```